# Can I see when and where my Facebook account was accessed?

Tags: facebook, security

Does Facebook keep records of when I, or someone else, accesses or logs into my account? I want to be able to see the access log from my homepage.

My computer was recently stolen and my Facebook was accessed. Aside from the Bing map that is used to show where the infraction took place, is there any way to find out the IP address that was used or the physical address rather than just the general location?

I have been keeping in touch with police on this matter and would like to call them with something more concrete than a general vicinity if that is possible.

Comment: They most certainly do (see [here](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16462/how-does-facebook-know-where-i-live)), but I doubt you will be able to access the respective data. Best case scenario would be for the data to be requested by the police from Facebook, but that's a long shot.

Comment: Also, you should consider using a laptop tracking software in the future. See [this](http://superuser.com/questions/77039/laptop-tracking-system) question on Superuser for details.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried going to `Account Settings` -> `Security` -> `Active Sessions`?

The `Active Sessions` page shows a list of sessions that are currently open - whether they be other browsers on the same computer or different locations.  You have the option to end any of the active sessions at any time.

**To see the IP address used to calculate the location**, just **hover over the location**.  For example, in the `Location` field, it might say: `Philadelphia, PA`.  Just hover your mouse over it, and it will say `Location estimated based on IP = 12.345.67.89.01` (example IP address used).

[image]

<sub>(excuse the white boxes, those represent sensitive locational data).</sub>